# How to stretch text in heading and paragraph

Tags: css

Is there are any line-height alternative for making text wider?

What I tried is using `text-align:justify`, but it only stretch first line of the paragraph.

I need to stretch the whole text.

Answer (score 1):

a super basic example without any more fancy stuff:

```css
        h1:hover{
            letter-spacing: 1.5rem;
        }
```

```html
<h1>Text</h1>
```

is that what you were looking for?
If not let me know what you mean with "stretch"

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform scale to stretch the text.

```css
.stretched {
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transform:scale(2,1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(2,1); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(2,1); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(2,1); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(2,1); /* W3C */
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Normal</p>
<p class="stretched">Stretched</p>
```